# Intellij Spring plugin initialization error

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, plugins

I installed the IdeaSpring plugin but unable to use it. When starting IntelliJ it throws an exception with root cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "IC-162.1628.40"
```

Im using community edition. Is there a fix available?

Ultimately I would like a plugin that checks your application context and annotations and highlights invalid injection with a warning and was thinking about writing one if time permits. Is there something similar already available?

Answer (score 0):

No. [It was updated 10 years ago.](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/106?pr=idea)